# Is this possible to do using plain BiFunction in method definition

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

I had the following problem: a method should take in a bi-function that takes 2 arguments - one is of type `Collection<T>` and the other is `T`; the actual function could be actually `Collection::remove` or `Collection::add`, or a more complex operation; the actual function is used for more than a dozen of collection and there are several types of values and collections in the function.

Initially there was no genericity - there were just `Collection<String>`s and elements were `String`s so declaring the argument as `BiFunction<Collection<String>, String, Boolean>` worked just well:

```
List<String> idCodes;
void visitElement(Element e, 
                  BiFunction<Collection<String>, String, Boolean> elementOp) {
    elementOp.apply(idCodes, e.getIdCode());
}
```

However then I added other types of collections too, and found that I could no longer find out how to use `BiFunction` generically:

```
List<String> idCodes;
List<Integer> weights;

void visitElement(Element e, 
                  BiFunction<...> elementOp) {
    elementOp.apply(idCodes, e.getIdCode());
    elementOp.apply(weights, e.getWeight());
}
```

but failed - I could just get compile errors in one place or another no matter what I used for type parameters it would fail.

One of my attempts was

```
<T> void visitElement(Element e, 
                      BiFunction<Collection<T>, T, Boolean> elementOp)
```

would fail not when passing in `Collection::add` but when actually applying the function to `Collection<String>` and `String`; or `Collection<Integer>` and `int`.

Then I made another interface:

```
interface ElementOp {
    <T> boolean apply(Collection<T> collection, T item);
}
```

And not so surprisingly this now works exactly as I wanted. Therefore my question is:

Do I really have to use

```
interface ElementOp {
    <T> boolean apply(Collection<T> collection, T item);
}

void visitElement(Element e, 
                  ElementOp elementOp) {
    elementOp.apply(idCodes, e.getIdCode());
    elementOp.apply(weights, e.getWeight());
}
```

or would it be somehow possible to use `BiFunction` for this case?

P.S. I am using Eclipse 4.3 Mars Java compiler, so it might just be that this might not work because of a some bug there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not use a `BiFunction` with `T` generic that handles both cases (`String` and `Integer`).

This code could not compile :

```
<T> void visitElement(Element e,  
        BiFunction<Collection<T>, T, Boolean> elementOp) {  
   ...
   elementOp.apply(idCodes, e.getIdCode());
   elementOp.apply(weights, e.getWeight());
}
```

as  `BiFunction` is a generic class and you parameterized it with `Collection<T>` and `T` as function arguments.
So you can only pass `Collection<T>` and `T` objects/variables while you pass 
`Collection<String>` and `String` in the fist call and `Collection<Integer>` and `Integer` in the second one.

With this custom interface, things are different :

```
interface ElementOp {
    <T> boolean apply(Collection<T> collection, T item);
}
```

This works :

```
elementOp.apply(idCodes, e.getIdCode());
elementOp.apply(weights, e.getWeight());
```

as contrary to `BiFunction` it may accept as parameters any variable declared with any class.
The thing to retain is that `ElementOp` is not a generic class.
 `T` is indeed only a method scope generic that infers the type of the types of the passed arguments.

---

To address your requirement : invoking multiple times the same method (`Collection.add()` or `Collection.remove()`) but with args of different types (`String` or `Integer`), you don't want to use a generic `BiFunction<T,Collection<T>, Boolean>`.
The custom functional interface you introduced suits much better.

Answer (score 2):

Well your first attempt did not work because when you have something like this:

```
<T> void visitElement(Element e, BiFunction<Collection<T>, T, Boolean> elementOp) {
    // some code        
}
```

All that `visitElement` knows about are `T` types; it knows that `elementOp` is of type `BiFunction<Collection<T>, T, Boolean>`; a `T` that will be inferred by the compiler.

I don't see any reason to introduce another `interface` here, when you can simply change the method a bit. Also notice that I've used `BiConsumer` and not `BiFunction` since you are not using the result anyway:

```
 void visitElement(T value, BiConsumer<Collection<T>, T> elementOp, Collection<T> elements) {
        elementOp.accept(elements, value);
 }
```

And use it:

```
    BiConsumer<Collection<String>, String> bi = Collection::remove;

    Element e = ...
    Collection<String> idCodes...;
    visitElement(e.getIdCode(), bi, idCodes);
```